# Upload user profile picture in php Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i upload user profile picture, according to the user_id ? I am trying to able every particular user to upload a photo on their profile and store in database. i dont know how to proceed this requirements so here i provided my code , would appreciate if you can help me how to proceed.
Here is my profile.php view

```
<div class="profile-img">
                <?php if (!empty($user->photo)): ?>
               <img src="/uploads/<?php echo $user->photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user->photo; ?>">
                  <?php endif;?>
                  <!-- <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt=""/> -->
                  
                  <?php echo form_open_multipart('users'); ?>
                   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>" />
                 <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                     <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                      <input type="file" name="file" />
                      <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Upload photo" />
                </form>
                
                </div>
            </div>
```

and here is my Profile.php Controller where i get all details that required for my profile view.

```
    function index()
{

     $user_id =  $this->session->userdata('admin');
    if(empty($user_id)){
         redirect('admin/login');
     }
    
   $data['userInfo'] = $this->profile_model->myProfile($user_id);
    
     if($user_id == 3){ // admin
        $data['project12'] = $getAllProjects = $this->profile_model->getAdminProjects();

        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($getAllProjects);
        //die;
        $new_array = array();
        foreach($getAllProjects as $key => $row) {
            $new_array[$key]['id'] = $row->id; 
            $new_array[$key]['delete_flag'] = $row->delete_flag; 
            $new_array[$key]['project_name'] = $row->project_name; 
            $new_array[$key]['client_name'] = $row->client_name; 
            $new_array[$key]['company'] = $row->company; 
            $new_array[$key]['project_manager'] = $row->project_manager; 
            $sec_array = explode(",",$row->support_staff);
            if(is_array($sec_array) ){
                foreach($sec_array as $row1){
                    $new_array[$key]['support_staff'][] = $this->profile_model->getUsernameByID($row1);

                }
            }
        }
        
        //print_r($new_array);die;
        $data['project'] = $new_array;

        $data['task_list'] = $this->task_model->getAllTasks();

        $data['incident_list'] = $this->incidents_model->getAllIncidents();


//      echo "<pre>";
// print_r($data['incident_list']);
//      die;

     }else{ // others
         $data['project'] = $this->profile_model->getById_myProjects($user_id);
         $data['task_list'] = $this->task_model->getTaskByUserID($user_id);
         $data['incident_list'] = $this->incidents_model->getIncidentByUserID($user_id);

     }
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') 
    {
    $this->upload_photo();
    }else{
    $this->load->view('users', [
    //'errors' => $this->upload_errors,
    'users'  => $this->profile_model->get_all()]);
    }



     $this->load->view('admin/profile/index',$data);
}


     $this->load->view('admin/profile/index',$data);
}
private function upload_photo()
    {
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $existing_photo = $this->profile_model->get_photo($user_id)->photo;
    if ($existing_photo && file_exists("./uploads/{$existing_photo}")) {
        unlink("./uploads/{$existing_photo}");
    }
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
        $this->upload_errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    $photo = $this->upload->data()['file_name'];
    $this->profile_model->update_photo($user_id, $photo);
   }
```

And here is my profile_model

```
function get_all($user_id)
 {
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM profile_details where user_id =$user_id");
      return $query->result();

 }


 function get_photo()
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT photo FROM profile_details where user_id= $user_id");

}


function update_photo($user_id, $photo)
{
    $this->db->update('profile_details', ['photo' => $photo], ['user_id' => $user_id]);
}
```

[image: Here is profile_details table]

[image: And here is the frontend view]

[image]

please help me how can i upload and store photo for every particular user.

Comment: what is your Codeigniter version?

Comment: codeigniter 3.1.11

Comment: I will try to help you and will post my answer a bit later

Answer (score 0):

So, for uploading photo you need at least three things:

- form where file can be chosen and submitted
- controller which can handle such a request and save file on the server
- database field where you save name (or full path) of the uploaded file to have possibility to show or delete it later

In short, I would recommend you to follow documentation about [creating new items](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html#create-news-items) and [uploading files](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html).

But also I can provide you some pieces of code.

1.Let's say, we have such a form for uploading file:

```
<!-- in such a way you can show already uploaded photo -->
<?php if (!empty($user->photo)): ?>
    <img src="/uploads/<?php echo $user->photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user->photo; ?>" width="50">
<?php endif;?>

<!-- pay attention to the hidden field that contains user_id that will be needed during saving the file 
and also to the "multipart" attribute that is required for uploading files.
CodeIgniter automatically can add these attributes using form_open_multipart function -->
<?php echo form_open_multipart('users'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>" />
        <input type="file" name="photo" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload photo" />
</form>
```

2.Then you should prepare you controller to receive these data. In my example this is a `Users` controller with `index` method:

```
/**
 * Index Page for Users controller.
 * It shows a list of existing users for GET method and tries to save user's photo for POST
 */
public function index()
{
    // if we send a form on these method then try to save uploaded file
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
        $this->upload_photo();
    }

    // otherwise, show list of existing users and possible uploading errors
    $this->load->view('users', [
        'errors' => $this->upload_errors,
        'users'  => $this->user_model->get_all()]);
}

/**
 * Method for saving user's profile photo
 */
private function upload_photo()
{
    // get user id from hidden form field
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

    // delete existing file if it exists
    $existing_photo = $this->user_model->get_photo($user_id)->photo;
    if ($existing_photo && file_exists("./uploads/{$existing_photo}")) {
        unlink("./uploads/{$existing_photo}");
    }

    // "photo" is the name of input element in uploading form
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
        // save uploading errors to show them on the page
        $this->upload_errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }

    // get file name from uploaded data
    $photo = $this->upload->data()['file_name'];

    // save uploaded file name to database for current user
    $this->user_model->update_photo($user_id, $photo);
}
```

You can [configure](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences) folder for uploading files and other restrictions. In this example uploading folder is `uploads` in the project root.

3.In database model you'll need only two simple methods for getting and updating `photo` field in `users` table:

```
/**
 * Class User_model
 */
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $table_name = 'users';

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function get_all()
     {
         return $this->db->get($this->table_name)->result();
     }

    /**
     * Get filename of user's profile photo
     *
     * @param $user_id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get_photo($user_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('photo');

        return $this->db->get_where($this->table_name, ['id' => $user_id])->row();
    }

    /**
    * Update "photo" field for "Users" database table
    *
    * @param $user_id
    * @param $photo
    */
    public function update_photo($user_id, $photo)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table_name, ['photo' => $photo], ['id' => $user_id]);
    }
}
```

For these manipulation it is required to load several libraries and helpers. You can do it in `application/config/autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'upload');
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'file');
```

These basic stuff can be extended, for example, with [form validation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#explanation).

Comment: Thank you for explaination and help , i followed your guid, and updated my code , as you can see im getting the error , would you mind have a look and see if you can help me @Slava

Comment: Sorry for delay @RoxanaSlj ) Try to check errors by yourself, they often are self-explained. You did not pass a required parameter to `get_all` method.
But also the point is that this parameter is not in the right place as you can see. You should remove `$user_id` parameter from method `get_all` (call this method as you did before) and add this parameter to the `get_photo` method where it is really used in query.